# VBA Word expanding each find occurance by two lines

Tags: vba

Trying to join text of video caption into one paragraph, I want to delete all blank lines with 2 additional lines. For example:

1
00:00:04,350 --> 00:00:07,609
This tutorial will show how to seamlessly transfer

2
00:00:07,609 --> 00:00:11,059
a model from Revit structure to ETABS

etc, I would the result to be: This tutorial will show how to
seamlessly transfer a model from Revit structure to ETABS,...

My best try is and is giving incomplete results :(

```
Sub DelExpandEmpty()
 Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph
 Dim var
 For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    If Len(oPara.Range) = 1 Then
        oPara.Range.Select
        Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=3
        Selection.Expand wdLine
        Selection.Delete
    End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
```

Comment: Excellent A.S.H. Thank you very much